# Parallel Computation with the possibility of calculation failure

Tags: parallelization, monitoring

**I would like to use *Mathematica* to speed-up a parallel calculation.**

I envisage each sub-process producing a list of 4 million machine reals. My problem is that sometimes the sub-process (based around [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html)) fails and the list is shorter than expected.

When this happens I would like to reject the list and re-try the calculation using slightly different initial conditions. What I need is an arrangement where I can submit the individual calculation to sub-process and have *Mathematica* wait for any sub-process to complete and then test if it really reached the end of the calculation.

**Is there a general "submit & wait" parallel programming mechanism in *Mathematica*?**

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Concurrency.html

Comment: A combination of `ParallelSubmit` and `WaitNext`.

Comment: Many thanks rhermans for a detailed and complete answer. I've not done parallel programming before and so it may take a little time to get to grips with your code.

Answer (score 6):

This is my way, based on [`ParallelSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelSubmit.html) and [`WaitNext`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WaitNext.html).

Here is a task that may take long time to finish and fails 50% of the time. We want to return not only the result, but also metadata that would allow us call the task again, analyze performance and have a decent log of what's happening.

```
task[s_] := Block[
  {
   p = RandomInteger[9],
   success
  },
  Pause[p]; (* adds some dramatism *)
  success = RandomChoice[ {True, False}];
  <|
   "parameter" -> s,
   "success" -> success,
   "kernel" -> $KernelID,
   "wait" -> p,
   "result" -> If[success, 42, $Failed]
   (* Answer to the Ultimate Question of... *)
   |>
  ]
```

The following function checks a list of [`EvaluationObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationObject.html) and resubmit a task if it isn't a success. If the queue is not empty, it retrieves the next task using `WaitNext` and logs the result. Then, if the return is considered a success, the value is saved into `resultList` . Otherwise, the task is submitted again using `ParallelSubmit`. The queue of tasks is updated accordingly.

```
check[] := Block[
  {return, evalobj, rest},
  If[
   Length[eids] > 0,
   {return, evalobj, rest} = WaitNext[eids];
   AppendTo[taskLog, return];
   If[return["success"],
    AppendTo[resultList, return["result"]], (* Success *)
    AppendTo[rest,                          (* Failure *)   
      With[
       {par = return["parameter"]},
       ParallelSubmit[task[par]]            (* Submit again *)
       ]];
    ];
   eids = rest;                             (* Update queue *)
   ]
  ]
```

Define empty lists for results and logs, launch kernels if necessary and distribute the definition of `task`.

```
eids = {};
resultList = {};
taskLog = {};
LaunchKernels[];
DistributeDefinitions[task]
```

Then we submit all the tasks using [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) and [`ParallelSubmit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelSubmit.html). Notice we need to use [`With`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) so the parameter value is given correctly to the `task` function.

```
eids = Table[
   With[
    {par = k},
    ParallelSubmit[ task[par] ]
    ]
   , {k, 20}
];
```

And keep checking for results until the list of evaluations tasks empties.

```
While[Length[eids] > 0, check[]]
```

See how the queue empties, 4 kernels working at the time, failed tasks are resubmitted and added at the end of the queue.

[image]

The evaluation log shows all attempts, successes and failures

[image]

Comment: Well I've modified rhermans' code to use my routines and I'm delighted to report it works flawlessly. Many thanks to you rhermans.