# Monitoring progress & feeding new job to subkernels which finished their computations via ParallelEvaluate

Tags: parallelization

Although the question is abstract, please suppose that we have a task that needs a large data and corresponding memory consumption, but we would like to parallelize it.

The large data is assumed now that can be loaded on my machine's memory.

For example, although this is too much trivial, suppose there is a set of many integers, and we would like to find their prime factorizations.

Serial computation is slow; hence we should split the data set and run the task on each subkernels.

For such problems, I usually use `ParallelEvaluate`.

Firstly I split the large data into smaller ones (but they are still large).

If we use `ParallelTable` or something which parallelizes the task automatically, the program will distribute each small data sets to subkernels.

However, I will not think that this does work well from my experience since sometimes it takes so long time to load it (I do not clarify the reason).

Thus I get used to preparing exported small data sets in advance, and I write `ParallelEvaluate[Import[*some_data.mx*]]`.

Then on each subkernel, the task can be run.

This seems to work well, and indeed it does, but sometimes there appear some subkernels that finish their tasks quicker than others.

Therefore, I would like to monitor the subkernels and feed new jobs to them which finished their tasks already.

With `ParallelTable`, we may use `Method->"FinestGrained"`, but I think that we have to write in a somewhat more explicit way to do that with `ParallelEvaluate`.

Do you have any idea?

I feel sorry if the problem is so trivial.

Comment: I would suggest you try something like `ParallelMap[(Import[#];(* processing code *))&, {"data1.mx", ...}]` - this way you don't have to reinvent the wheel, and you can just use `Method->"FinestGrained"` or similar. And if you run into any issues, you can ask a more concrete question about those issues.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202315/10397) for a strategy for submitting task dynamically, designed to resubmit tasks that have failed, but of general use with some modifications.

Comment: About your question, your way of asking is very broad and very verbose. More focused questions, with minimal working examples of code are most welcomed here.